# No numpy function works in numba cuda.jit

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I've tried running this code

```
@cuda.jit
def arr():
    a = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.], dtype=np.float32)
arr()
```

But it results in this error `TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.array' or unsupported use of the function.` I don't understand why that happens, shouldn't cuda.jit support most if not all numpy functions? It also occurs with np.zeros and np.empty, and probably all other functions (it works with normal @jit even when nopython is true)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the [docs](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/overview.html#missing-cuda-features), you'll find that unlike with numba's two basic compilation modes `@jit` and `@njit`, `numba` CUDA supports very few numpy features.

Namely, it only supports:

> - accessing ndarray attributes .shape, .strides, .ndim, .size, etc..
> - scalar ufuncs that have equivalents in the math module; i.e. np.sin(x[0]), where x is a 1D array.
> - indexing and slicing works.

And all the following (which includes array creation too) are not supported:

> - array creation APIs.
> - array methods.
> - functions that returns a new array.

Comment: Also I think it's good to add this quote from [docs](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/cudapysupported.html#numpy-support): _Due to the CUDA programming model, dynamic memory allocation inside a kernel is inefficient and is often not needed. Numba disallows any memory allocating features. This disables a large number of NumPy APIs. For best performance, users should write code such that each thread is dealing with a single element at a time._